# State transitions in ui-router and resolve from a parent abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to show a loading animation during state transitions in a Angular ui-router application.

Check out the following code

```
$stateProvider
.state("app",
{
    abstract: true,
    url: "",
    template: "<ui-view/>",
    controller: "appController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    resolve: {
        result_data_abstract: function ($q, $timeout))
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve("from abstract");
            }, 500);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
.state("app.real",
{
    url: "/real/{id}",
    templateUrl: "somepath/template.html",
    controller: "realController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    resolve: {
        result_data_real: function ($q, $timeout))
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve("from real");
            }, 500);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
.state("app.real2",
{
    url: "/real2/{id}",
    templateUrl: "somepath2/template.html",
    controller: "real2Controller",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    // Note no resolve
})
```

So both concrete states inherit from the abstract one - the abstract class has a resolve.

However, only one of the real (concrete) states has a resolve of its own.

My goal is to show a loading animation during transitions using the following code:

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState) {
            console.log("stateChangeStart", toState);
            if (toState.resolve) {
                showSpinner();
            }
        });

$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
    console.log("stateChangeSuccess", toState);
    if (toState.resolve) {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

Since the abstract state the concrete states inherit from has a resolve, I expected '`toState.resolve`' to be true every time, getting the resolves from the abstract parent state it inherits from.

That however is not the case - when I load app.real2, '`toState.resolve`' is null.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: View transition will be instantaneos. You won't even see the loader. Maybe you want to show a loader while you are performing http requests?

Comment: I think this comment ^ is correct. Why is it important to check the resolve before showing the spinner? You can just show and hide it, and if you cache the result from the resolve then you won't see the spinner (Or just for a few milliseconds. You can also add `params` to specific states where you want to show the spinner and check `toParams.showSpinner` (for example) instead

Comment: You will see it if your resolve takes a second or two.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading an entire "page"?  If so I do this by calling it in run.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function () {
        console.log("stateChangeStart");
        showSpinner();
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function () {
        console.log("stateChangeSuccess");
        hideSpinner();
    });
});
```

I don't use *$stateChangeSuccess* and *toState* but it looks like it might work as well.